# What should be outcome of this Mock test?

Tags: spock

I am new to `Spock` f/w and trying to learn it. I've written some sample code, where I expect that `println(list.size())` statement under `when` section will print the value `10` (as this call been stubbed under given section). But I am getting 0 (seems like a default value for return type i.e `int`). Can you please help me understand it?

```
def "size of list test "() {
    given:
    ArrayList list = Mock()
    list.size() >> 10

    when:
    list.add(1)
    list.add(2)
    println(list.size())

    then:
    1*list.size()
}
```

Comment: If you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

When you both *mock* and *verify* the interaction the value returned form mock should be configured in `then` block. The following example works well:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def 'sample spec'() {
        given:
        ArrayList list = Mock()

        when:
        list.add(1)
        list.add(2)
        println(list.size())

        then:
        1 * list.size() >> 10
     }
}
```